# Listing: Syntax highlighting for SPARQL query?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I use the following listing to show a SPARQL query:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b, caption=SPARQL query, label=lst:sparql]
PREFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?url ?name
WHERE {
   ?url rdf:type java:Package .
   ?url rdfs:label ?name
}
```

But now I don't know which language tag I should set, since SPARQL is not built-in. I also tried to define my own highlighting, but I couldn't achieve a good result. Is there any macro available for highlighting SPARQL queries?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Load the defined language SQL and define more keywords, if needed. Alternetivily write a package `SPARQL.sty` with a a complete language definition. Choose the one from `SQL` as template which is in the file `lstlang1.sty`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL,morekeywords={PREFIX,java,rdf,rdfs,url}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b, caption=SPARQL query, label=lst:sparql,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,frame=single]
PREFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?url ?name
WHERE {
   ?url rdf:type java:Package .
   ?url rdfs:label ?name
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that these are sample-specific formatting instructions, as the prefixes have to be listed explicitly. Using a given string both as a prefix and as an identifier would be problematic, and in the depicted example, `java` and `rdf` are also bolded nonsensically in the base IRIs.

Answer (score 12):

If you use the `minted` package, you can write your own lexer quite easily by writing a python module for Pygments. I wrote a little example [on my blog](http://www.raphink.info/2011/03/syntax-highlighting-in-latex.html).

Edit:
There's actually a SPARQL lexer for Pygments [in this repository](http://www.openvest.com/trac/browser/tools/trunk/pygments/lexers/sw.py), so you can

- Download the sw.py file

  ```
  $ mkdir -p swlexers/swlexers
  $ cd swlexers
  $ wget http://www.openvest.com/trac/browser/tools/trunk/pygments/lexers/sw.py?format=txt -O swlexers/__init__.py
  ```
- Write a setup.py file for it

  ```
  $ cat setup.py
  """
  Sparql syntax highlightin for Pygments.
  """
  from setuptools import setup
  entry_points = """
  [pygments.lexers]
  sparql = swlexers:SparqlLexer
  """
  setup(
      name         = 'swlexers',
      version      = '0.1',
      description  = __doc__,
      packages     = ['swlexers'],
      entry_points = entry_points
  )
  ```
- Install the module:

  ```
  $ sudo python setup.py install
  ```
- Check that the module was installed:

  ```
  $ pygmentize -L | grep -i sparql
  ```
- Use it in your code with `minted`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{minted}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{minted}{sparql}
  PREFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
  SELECT ?url ?name
  WHERE {
     ?url rdf:type java:Package .
     ?url rdfs:label ?name
  }
  \end{minted}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image: Sparql in minted]

Comment: Inside lists, you need to indent with 8 spaces (otherwise just 4).

Comment: see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks for all the ways to format code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to indenting with 4 in SE sites, and then indenting button didn't seem to fix anything...

Comment: Amazing answer. Can I perhaps “steal” this as a how-to for the documentation, once I get the time to bundle a new release of `minted`?

Comment: Certainly @Konrad. I've struggled to add my own lexer to Pygments to use with `minted` (still don't get it fully I'm afraid), so I'm happy to share the little I've figured out ;-)

Comment: @Konrad The only suggestion I'd make is to change `cat setup.py' (since the user should not type cat). These are brilliant helpful instructions and I'm really glad to find these lexers. Now just need an RDFa one! :-D

Comment: @Jodi Seriously? no. `cat` is fine here. It does exactly what is wanted. Sure you could use `more` but that’s one letter … more … to type and has no advantages here. I’m all in favour of replacing unnecessary `cat` but this is taking it to ridiculous lengths.

Comment: @Konrad I was thinking `edit`, or perhaps "Write a setup file, here is what it should look like" It depends on the perspective -- the earlier an later instructions are literal commands to type on the command line. That's just to avoid potential confusion, for accessibility: Not everybody knows `cat` (though they should).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers provide much fully features ways to achieve this.  For completeness sake I would note that you can also just use the `\lstdefinelanguage` command from the listings package to define a completely new language.

The following is the crude definition of SPARQL I've used in the past.

```
% Language Definitions for SPARQL
\lstdefinelanguage{sparql}{
morecomment=[l][\color{olivegreen}]{\#},
morestring=[b][\color{blue}]\",
morekeywords={SELECT,CONSTRUCT,DESCRIBE,ASK,WHERE,FROM,NAMED,PREFIX,BASE,OPTIONAL,FILTER,GRAPH,LIMIT,OFFSET,SERVICE,UNION,EXISTS,NOT,BINDINGS,MINUS,a},
sensitive=true
}
```

You'll notice I didn't bother to fill out all the keywords for the built in functions

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to StackExchange, and don't know well the forum ; but I think this page should be updated.

I first followed the `SQL` solution, then the `\lstdefinelanguage` : both of these solutions fail with comments.

However, I found that there is a SPARQL definition in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang3.sty` (install on Ubuntu 18.04) :

```
.../usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings$ grep -i sparql *
lstlang3.sty:%% SPARQL definition (c) 2006 Christoph Kiefer
lstlang3.sty:\lst@definelanguage{SPARQL}%
```

As you can see, it was written in 2006 (but maybe not in listings package in 2011 or 2013, when the answers on this page were posted?).

Here's a sample code to compare the solutions :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
    frame = single,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{sparqlB}{
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
    language=SQL,
    morekeywords={SELECT},      
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{blue},
    sensitive=true,
}

\begin{document}

    -- SPARQL in lstlang3.sty : 
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=sparql]
        # comment with 'single quotes' = OK
        SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
    \end{lstlisting}

    -- SQL solution :       
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL]
        # comment with 'single quotes' = NOT RECOGNIZED
        SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
    \end{lstlisting}    

    -- \\lstdefinelanguage solution
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=sparqlB]
    # comment with 'single quotes' = NOT RECOGNIZED
    SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
    \end{lstlisting}    


\end{document}
```

---

EDIT :
Actually the `\lstdefinelanguage` works for comments if I change the order of options

```
\lstdefinelanguage{
language=SQL,  % <-- has to be before morecomment
morecomment=[l]{\#},
[...]
```

or remove `language=SQL`

But the definition in .sty file is more complete, of course.