# Listing code going out of page

Tags: listings

I'm using listings to display my codes. I'm getting some issues. First, the codes when it is too long, it is going out of page as shown [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/MintedOutofPage.png). Secondly, the codes are in SPARQL. It is recognising some of the variables I use as SQL keywords and highlighted them as shown [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/syn.png) where *Class* is inspite being a variable is being highlighted as a keyword. My codes are as follows:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b, caption=Retrieval of Individuals, label=listing:sparql_getallindividuals,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily]
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  wo:   <http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?individual ?type ?name
  WHERE
    { ?individual rdf:type ?type .
      ?individual wo:commonName ?name
      FILTER ( ?type IN (wo:Kingdom, wo:Phylum, wo:Class, wo:Order, wo:Species, wo:Family, wo:Genus) )
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is preamble of my report:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

 \lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  numbers=none,
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  tabsize=3
}
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type,ma-id}% list your attributes here
}
```

Comment: `minted` doesn't wrap long lines unlike `listings`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23663/minted-truncates-the-code-if-it-doesnt-fit-into-one-page, for sparql highlighting, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14927/listing-syntax-highlighting-for-sparql-query

Comment: Oh sorry, in fact i'm using listing itself, I just edited my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the line breaking problem, you can use the `breaklines=true` option:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

 \lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  numbers=none,
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  tabsize=3
}
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type,ma-id}% list your attributes here
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b, caption=Retrieval of Individuals, label=listing:sparql_getallindividuals,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily]
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  wo:   <http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?individual ?type ?name
  WHERE
    { ?individual rdf:type ?type .
      ?individual wo:commonName ?name
      FILTER ( ?type IN (wo:Kingdom, wo:Phylum, wo:Class, wo:Order, wo:Species, wo:Family, wo:Genus) )
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the other issue, you haven't provided enough information to detect the problem.

Comment: Thanks, here is the other issue I am getting, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/syn.png, are you see *class* is being highlighted.

Comment: @user1774937 Yes, I see, but I need the *settings* you are using for the highlighting.

Comment: the preamble of my report, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/preamble.txt

Comment: @user1774937 Please add the relevant information to your question. Compose a little *complete* document (like the one in my answer) with the relevant settings and showing the problem mentioned and add this document as an edit to your question.

Comment: u right, its done

Comment: @user1774937 Sorry, but that's not a little, complete document. Remove all unnecessary information and keep just all that is really relevant to your problem and complete the code until it's complete.

Comment: I'm a latex beginner, I removed what I think is not relevant

Comment: @user1774937 I updated my answer using the settings in your question. As you can see I don't get the string "Class" highlighted, so something else must be going on in your document, and without the actual offending code is almost impossible to provide effective help. Please compose a little, complete document (again, like the one in my answer) containing the settings allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: I suppose this issue must be in the preamble??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10000/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-user1774937)