# Syntax highlighting for SPARQL query in a listing? (works fine in minted environment but not in listing with mint)

Tags: listings, color, highlighting, minted, syntax

I can do syntax highlighting in the `minted` environment, for any SPARQL query using [this Pygments lexer](http://www.openvest.com/trac/browser/tools/trunk/pygments/lexers/sw.py) thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14929/7000).

My problem is how to get SPARQL syntax highlighting to work with `mint` in a `listing` (so that I can get a label and a caption). I am missing the BOM/EOM escape code.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

%Minted environment works fine 
\begin{minted}{sparql}
PREFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?url ?name
WHERE {
   ?url rdf:type java:Package .
   ?url rdfs:label ?name
}
\end{minted}

%Mint in listing gives runaway argument error
\begin{listing}[H]
\mint{SPARQL}
PREFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?url ?name
WHERE {
   ?url rdf:type java:Package .
   ?url rdfs:label ?name
\caption{Example of a listing.}
\label{lst:example}
\end{listing}

Listing \ref{lst:example} contains an example of a listing.

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile the above example with `pdflatex -shell-escape` I get:

```
Runaway argument?
REFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetVerb.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.17 ...zer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
```

This example from the [mint manual](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) works fine:

```
\begin{listing}[H]
\mint{cl}/(car (cons 1 ’(2)))/
\caption{Example of a listing.}
\label{lst:example}
\end{listing}

Listing \ref{lst:example} contains an example of a listing.
```

I seem to be missing the escape code (`/` in cl) that signals the beginning and end of a message for SPARQL. Thoughts?

I'd also consider other approaches to syntax highlighting (e.g. other libraries that use Pygments); since I want colors, [this b+w highlighting solution isn't what I need](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14937/7000).

Comment: What is it that you want to do that the `minted` environment can't?

Comment: I need a label and a caption.

Comment: You should be able to put the `minted` environment inside the `listing` environment, with the label and caption after the end of the `minted` environment (on a separate line).

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of trying that! Indeed, that works. Want to add it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks @g-poore !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `minted` environment by putting it inside the `listing` environment, with the label and caption after the end of the `minted` environment (on a separate line).  The nested environments will work fine.

The `\mint` command is for typesetting a single line of code, so the code must delimited by a pair of matched characters.  For example, `\mint{<language>}/<code>/` uses the `/` character as a delimiter.

Comment: Working solution, for clarity: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}{sparql}
PREFIX java: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2009/06/java.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?url ?name
WHERE {
   ?url rdf:type java:Package .
   ?url rdfs:label ?name
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of a listing.}
\label{lst:example}
\end{listing}

Listing \ref{lst:example} contains an example of a listing.

\end{document}`